# SVN externals, how to handle same paths

Tags: svn, version-control, branching-and-merging, visual-sourcesafe, svn-externals

I want to migrate from VSS to SVN, and the reason of my question lies behind the logic which these 2 systems use.
My enterprise project has single source, but few files from UI,(jsp pages,etc.) are different. So as in VSS we have branched them, and after getting the general, the CompanyA's webresources are replaced with the general equivalence of these resources.
So as i know in SVN the solution is resolved with externals. But I have a problem.
Consider my project structure is like this:

> **/sources ->which are common**
>   **/webresources ->general Webresources**
>     - webresources\services\service1\jsp\service1View.jsp
>    - webresources\services\service2\jsp\service2Content.jsp
>
> **webresources.CompanyA ->this directory has only specific branches for companyA** 
>  
>   - webresources\services\service1\jsp\service1View.jsp
>   **webresources.CompanyB->this directory has only specific branches for companyB** 
>    - webresources\services\service2\jsp\service2Content.jsp

Can I have external which point to a single file from company's specific directory and gets the other content of that directory from the general directory? Or in SVN when it points the same path, the external content replaces the local checked out folder?

Comment: skip svn and move straight to git, much better.

Answer (score 1):

The answer partially depends on the version of Subversion that you're using.  Older versions could only do externals at the folder level, but newer versions are capable of doing externals at the file level.  Even if you are using the latest version, I recommend doing your externals at the folder level anyway.  You'll typically end up with a *lot* less maintenance work than if you have to update your externals metadata any time you add/remove/rename a file.

In your specific case, you could store all of the company-specific files in a folder named something like `webresources\services\service1\jsp\client` and have Subversion populate that directory using `svn:externals`.